# c++ error: 'std::string' has no member

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I am creating a directory program that prompts a user for a file name and reads the file into a string array. I'm have trouble in my SearchFirstName function.  I get an error:'std::string' has no member named 'userRecord'. I'm not sure how to fix this because userRecord is declared.

Header

```
#include<string>
using namespace std;

enum Title {Mr, Mrs, Ms, Dr, NA};

struct NameType {
   Title title;
   string firstName;
   string lastName;
};

struct AddressType {
   string street;
   string city;
   string state;
   string zip;
};

struct PhoneType {
  int areaCode;
  int prefix;
  int number;
};

struct entryType {
  NameType name;
  AddressType address;
  PhoneType phone;
};

const int MAX_RECORDS = 50;
```

Code

```
// string bookArray[MAX_RECORDS];
entryType bookArray[MAX_RECORDS];   //Solution
int bookCount = 0;

void OpenFile(string& filename, ifstream& inData)
{
do {
    cout << "Enter file name to open: ";
    cin >> filename;

    inData.open(filename.c_str());

    if (!inData)
        cout << "File not found!" << endl;

} while (!inData);


if(inData.is_open())
{

    for(int i=0; i<MAX_RECORDS;i++)
    {
        inData>> bookArray[bookCount];
        ++bookCount;
    }
}
}


void SearchFirstName(ifstream& inData)
{
   entryType userRecord; // Declaration of userRecord
   string searchName;

   string normalSearchName, normalFirstName;
   char choice;
   bool found = false;

   cout << "Enter first name to search for: ";
   cin >> searchName;

   for(int i = 0; i < bookCount; ++i){

  normalFirstName = NormalizeString(bookArray[i].userRecord.name.firstName);   
 // Convert retrieved string to all uppercase

    if (normalFirstName == normalSearchName) { // Requested name matches
        PrintRecord(bookArray[i].userRecord.name.firstName);
        cout << "Is this the correct entry? (Y/N)";
        cin >> choice;
        choice = toupper(choice);
        cout << endl;

        if (choice == 'Y') {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
// Matching name was found before the end of the file
if (inData && !found){
    cout << "Record found: " << endl;
    PrintRecord(userRecord);
    cout << endl;
}
else if (!found)   // End of file. Name not found.
{
    cout << searchName << " not found!" << endl << endl;
}

// Clear file fail state and return to beginning
inData.clear();
inData.seekg(0);
 }
```

Comment: What is the type of `bookArray`?

Comment: I suppose bookArray is a string array? and string has no member name userRecord. So what is not clear?

Comment: `bookArray` should be an array of `entryType` and i think it would be of type `string` which is why the error is thrown.Show us the `bookArray` definition.

Comment: I added the bookArray definition

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to fix the error.

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Comment: @n.m. I just accepted the answer. It doesn't allow you to accept the answer immediately it make you wait a few minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 string bookArray[MAX_RECORDS];
```

`bookArray` is of type string.It should be

```
 entryType bookArray[MAX_RECORDS];
```

Also

```
normalFirstName = NormalizeString(bookArray[i].userRecord.name.firstName);
```

`bookArray[i]` cannot have `userRecord` as a member.`userRecord` is variable that you have declared.
It should be

```
normalFirstName = NormalizeString(bookArray[i].name.firstName);
```

Comment: `entryType` still has no member named 'userRecord'.

Comment: @n.m. Was updating it.Thanks.